# Access generic type by brackets

Tags: typescript

I have the following class:

```
export abstract class BasicTable<T> {
    rows: T[];
    ...
}
```

where T is the type of the table rows.

For filtering the rows I have the following implementation:

```
private filter(data: T[]): T[] {
    const activeFilters = FilterService.getFilters();
   
    if(activeFilters.length) {
        return data.filter(row => {
            activeFilters.map(filter => this.matchesFilter(row, filter))
                         .filter(matches => !matches)
                         .length > 0 ? false : true
        });
    }
    else {
        return data;
    }
}

private matchesFilter(row: T, filter: Filter): boolean {
    return (row[filter.field] === filter.value); // I have kept it simple in this SO-question
}
```

But for `row[filter.field]` in the `matchesFilter()` method I get the following error:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'unknown'.
No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'unknown'.
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: can you please include the `Filter` type in your question?

Comment: I think the issue is that the generic type `T` can be literally anything, so we don't know whether indexing it with a string key is valid. If `row` MUST be an object of some sort, then I think you should specify that `T extends Record<PropertyKey, unknown` on your class, so that T is known to be some kind of object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index probably needs to be of type keyof T.
You can cast it to keyof T with

```
return (row[filter.field as keyof T] === filter.value);
```

[Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiCWIAuBTATtA3gKGn6wA9gHYRJoCuwShaAFAJRa76tIAW8EAdAG5ggKKaAF5oAIlRlxLVng5duAM3goQAE1ESVa9TNYBfWdAAOFAEYh4waP0EoAXNDJp4xAOYBuY2cvXoOhpOLm5e2EbYoJAwALIAngAqKGQASoQA7sysvlY2gZpikslI4t4RUVDQSWQAPAkAfFn4Of4AtmBIwOzJCMjodGgZTgkANAGIqGhOvZMMTuaEhCAoYMRNctBoKEgUaGsDGQDaKn1oyqoa0JDQANYocYRKVQC6oiJiJ5N8AkIMntAAegB0AAktB2GBeMI7iYkNB4HCIPBWiZlvC1goYABlADyAFoAI5CMjwEjGIzlEhkcanLTEFCZGb9P6RKlwqRINKZMT0zLxaqcjKMbxEUjs4p0hlVYo1fnFLn1YWs0hLFDcECEdx0DncdqdboQJn0DlcsafdAMP5AA)